# Goal Seek in multiple rows (with empty rows in the middle)

Tags: excel, vba

I want to perform a goal seek for several rows (I don't know exactly how many - in the code I have below it stops in row 100). The thing is, **for example**, if I have 10 rows, row number 5 can be empty. So I want it to skip from row 4 to row 6, then continue, then "jump" another empty row if they exist.

I want to set cell M2 to 0 by changing the value of cell K2. The same for row 3, row 4, etc. and I want it to skip empty rows.

Right now I just have this... a simple case

```
Sub GSeek()



Dim i As Long
For i = 2 To 100


    range("M" & i).GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=range("K" & i)


Next



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Dim i As Long

For i = 2 To 100
    If range("M" & i).Value <> "" Then
        range("M" & i).GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=range("K" & i)
    End If
Next i
```

Each time it just makes sure that the cell isn't empty. If it is, it'll just move to next i

Comment: Yes. Just put that in the middle of your loop and it'll go from 2 to 100.